# Error importing gi

Tags: python, gtk

This is the command I am trying to run and its output:

```
$ python2
Python 2.7.8 (default, Sep 24 2014, 18:26:21) 
[GCC 4.9.1 20140903 (prerelease)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import _gi
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gi/_gi.so: undefined symbol: g_type_check_instance_is_fundamentally_a
```

I have searched for this error, but could not find anything that helped.

These are the packages that I have installed:

```
$ pacman -Qs python
local/pygtk 2.24.0-3
    Python bindings for the GTK widget set
local/python 3.3.4-1
    Next generation of the python high-level scripting language
local/python-dbus-common 1.2.0-2
    Common dbus-python files shared between python-dbus and python2-dbus
local/python-gobject 3.14.0-2
    Python 3 bindings for GObject
local/python-gobject2 2.28.6-11
    Python 3 bindings for GObject2
local/python2 2.7.8-2
    A high-level scripting language
local/python2-cairo 1.10.0-1
    Python2 bindings for the cairo graphics library
local/python2-dbus 1.2.0-2
    Python 2.7 bindings for DBUS
local/python2-distutils-extra 2.38-1
    Enhancements to the Python build system
local/python2-gobject 3.14.0-2
    Python 2 bindings for GObject
local/python2-gobject2 2.28.6-11
    Python 2 bindings for GObject2
local/python2-pillow 2.3.0-3
    Python Imaging Library (PIL) fork. Python2 version.
local/python2-xdg 0.25-1
    Python library to access freedesktop.org standards
```

Dont know what I am missing here..

Solved:

Error was due to older version of glib2 package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be not a Python problem nor your code problem. `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gi/_gi.so` might be corrupted or compiled badly. Maybe you've put it in the wrong path.

**How to solve:** *upgrade glib2*

Comment: @AadityaBagga You might need to uninstall the package '_gi.so' belongs to and reinstall it from official site or using pip; if this doesn't work, download the source and compile it yourself.

Comment: The package was python2-gobject, and I had just installed it, so not sure reinstalling will make any difference..

Comment: @AadityaBagga 'Undefined symbol' is about _your system_, not Python. python2-gobject might depend on some package which is not installed.

Comment: The dependencies of python2-gobject are installed, as the package manager automatically resolves dependencies.. Perhaps there is an unlisted dependency?

Comment: Figured it out: upgrading the glib2 package fixed it ;) Thx for the pointers, marking it as solved; you might want to edit your post to include it.